# Why axios doesn't work with static nodejs server?

Tags: axios, sequelize.js

I'm having trouble getting my axios `.get` in production with React.

I created a nodeJS server with `express` to render my react page each time I want to refresh my page. That work.

But the problem is that it block my axios `.get()`. So, my page show normaly without the data I normaly get in dev mode.

[image]

BackEnd => **server.js** with `sequelize` module to manage my database

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

const db = require('./models');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});


const governmentCreateRouter = require('./routes/GovernmentCreate');
app.use("/governmentCreate", governmentCreateRouter);

db.sequelize.sync().then(() => {
    app.listen();
});
```

BackEnd => **GovernmentCreate.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { GovernmentCreate } = require('../models');

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    const listOfGovernments = await GovernmentCreate.findAll({
        include: {all: true}
    });
    res.json(listOfGovernments);
});
```

FrontEnd => Part of code inside my **GouvernmentWall.js** that is called with url `https://www.mon-gouvernement.fr/gouvernement-galerie`

```
const [governmentList, setGovernmentList] = useState([]);

axios.get(`https://www.mon-gouvernement.fr/GovernmentCreate`)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res.data);

                const resData = res.data;

                setGovernmentList(sortResData);

            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
```

After multi-searching I'm thinking that the problem come from  these lines in my server.js :

```
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
    });
```

But if I remove it, when I try to refresh my page I'm getting a white page diplay `Cannot GET /gouvernement-galerie`.

[image]

So I'm stocking with this issu. I need your help to move forward.

Comment: Think about the order in which your routes are applied...

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Could you be more specific please. I'm stocking for 2 days now, so I need really explanation.

Comment: `.get('/*'` handles **all** GET requests, responding from the build directory (to enable push-state routing in your SPA). So if that's _first_, how exactly do you expect any other route to be reachable? Did you look at the response Axios was getting?

Comment: That work ! I was unfamiliar with the importance of orders routes in nodeJs. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solve !**

As @jonrsharpe mentioned, I have to switch my `.get('/*'` to the bottom of my routes. My `server.js` look like :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

const db = require('./models');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

//************************************************
// ROUTES
//************************************************
const governmentCreateRouter = require('./routes/GovernmentCreate');
app.use("/governmentCreate", governmentCreateRouter);

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});


db.sequelize.sync().then(() => {
    app.listen();
});
```